# Excessive images are being stacked vertically and not hidden in jcarousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and ColdFusion. I don't know what version of jcarousel we are using, but this is where the plugin was gotten from...

```
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
```

I have a page that has a carousel that no longer works. I didn't build the page, but I need to fix it. Here's a link to the page:

```
http://dev.iqcatalogs.com/avcat/ctl1642/index.cfm?avprofile.detail=1443
```

The carousel has eight images on the right side. Only four of those images SHOULD show. Right now, all eight images are stacked vertically.

Any ideas on why this might not be working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I discovered that our skin.css was deleted and so not being loaded when called.

I downloaded the jcarousel again and uploaded skin.css.

Problem solved.